# Metro UI code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

i have written a code for creating a sample page using metro ui.
but the live tile function is not working. the tiles dont slide

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html>
    <head>
        <link href="stt.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tiles">
            <div class="live-tile" data-mode="slide">
                <div style="background-color:Red;">test 1</div>
                <div style="background-color:Orange;">test back</div>
            </div>
            <div class="live-tile" data-mode="flip">
                <div style="background-color:green;">test 2</div>
                <div style="background-color:red;">test 2 - back</div>
            </div>

<script src="metrojs.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>  
<script src="metrojs.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>  
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("Document loaded");
                $(".live-tile").liveTile();
                alert("exiting alert");
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

is the above code correct???

Comment: You may want to put the script loading in the `<head>` tag. Performance matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `jQuery` to be first , because `metrojs` uses jQuery,reorder js files like this :

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
<script src="metrojs.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>  
<script src="metrojs.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Also , i don't think you need both `metrojs.js` and `metrojs.min.js` ,only one of them,and i suggest to put jQuery in the head of your page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should be declared in your page `<head></head>` before the other js scripts. You should try using Firefox and firebug to error check, it would have helped you.